# Is it possible to destructure an object with default key names

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to take an object (with many keys) and destructure the entire object just using its default key values?
(Without typing all of the keys)

For example:

```
let myObject = {
    foo: "value1",
    bar: "value2",
};

const (do something special here?) = myObject;
console.log(foo); // "value1"
console.log(bar); // "value2"
```

This is NOT a question on how to do a regular destructure, I know how to do trivial destructuring like:

```
const {foo, bar} = myObject;
```

But for objects with 15+ keys and I know I want to use most of the values I am wondering if there is a way to destructure the object and just use the default key names from the object.

Comment: What does "default key names" mean? Does something like `Object.keys` work for you? Or `Object.entries`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Man I even looked for it before I asked...

Comment: I found it with [`destructure all properties automatically js`](https://www.google.com/search?q=destructure+all+properties+automatically+js)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Guess I need to up my searching game.